# How can I prevent from defaulting to InDesign's Start Workspace?

Tags: adobe-indesign, cc-2015

In InDesign when I close a file the application will automatically default to their `Start` workplace instead of my custom workspace.  How can I prevent InDesign from doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Indesign if you navigate to `Preferences -> General` or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> on the first line uncheck `Show "Start" Workspace When No Documents Are Open`:

[image]

After you've made the changes click the OK button.